# When create different Notifications from a query in Firebase I cannot extract exactly the Title

Tags: loops, firebase, notifications

I am able to create different notifications from different users inside a loop in firebase chat app (that update current notification correctly as messages keep coming).

But as the creation of notifications are inside a loop the put.extra method of the intent to open an activity always take the last parameters.So I cannot go to the desired location from the first notification.
I thought that better way is to get EXACTLY the title of the notification as exists in the notification area.This will fit exactly my needs!

Can I do this? Can I get exactly the title of any notification and pass it to the next activity despite the order of creation and order in the notification area?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with a different approach .I succeded by entering some dummy action on the resultIntent as:

`resultIntent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));`

And I dont need anymore to get the title of the notification!

Below is the whole code for the intent.Remember that the code is generated inside a for loop...

```
String tagStringForNotification = usermessageOfLast.getName();

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle(usermessageOfLast.getName() +"\t" + "said:")
    .setContentText(usermessageOfLast.getText())
    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));

mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
mBuilder.setLocalOnly(false);

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserToUserMessageNotification.class);
resultIntent.putExtra("chatsWith", tagStringForNotification);  

resultIntent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));

//flag to upddate current or create new one
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

//building the notification
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

mNotificationManager.notify(tagStringForNotification, notifyID, mBuilder.build());
```